# array value not updating and getting 0 instead

Tags: python, numpy

Hello everyone I have this function it takes a list and plot the cumulative averaged sum:

```py
def plot_avg_loss(losses):
  cum_loss=np.cumsum(np.array(losses))
  for i in range(cum_loss.shape[0]):
    print(cum_loss[i])
    a=(1/(i+1))*cum_loss[i]
    print(a)
    cum_loss[i]=(1/(i+1))*cum_loss[i]  #update !!!!
    print("------------------")
    print("---->",cum_loss[i]) #why is this not printing the same value as print(a)
    print("------------------")

  plt.plot(range(cum_loss.shape[0]),cum_loss)
  plt.title("cumulative loses")
  plt.show

plot_avg_loss(losses)
```

and this output (without the plots):

```
0
0.0
------------------
----> 0
------------------
0
0.0
------------------
----> 0
------------------
1
0.3333333333333333
------------------
----> 0
------------------
2
0.5
------------------
----> 0
------------------
```

what intrigued me here is why the `cum_loss`  (which is of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`) not updating. and getting 0 (printed after the `---->` instead of printing the same value as `a`.

I can work around it anyway but this behavior intreagued my curiosity and  I wanted to share it and understand why it is occuring.

Comment: Check the dtype.  is it integer?

Comment: yes it is indeed int64.

Comment: This is very hard to google so I'm struggling to find a better duplicate. The problem is the same: numpy arrays have a fixed dtype and assigning to subarrays will preserve this dtype by coercing the right-hand side to the given dtype. For an int array this means that assigning 0.3 ends up as 0, assigning 1.3 ends up as 1 etc. It gets truncated to an int as if by calling `int` on the float.

Comment: And of course the simplest solution which probably works is to pass  `np.cumsum(..., dtype=float)` in the first line of the function. (Or appending `.astype(float)` to the same line.)

Comment: Shouldn't need the iteration  `cum_loss=cum_loss/np.arange(1,cum_loss.shape[0]+1)`